# Magento2 - How to remove item from wishlist?

Tags: magento2, customer, wishlist, delete

I want to `remove an item from wishlist in magento2 with  wishlist id or wish list item id`, how can do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to inject several classes in your constructor

```
protected $_wishlistProviderInterface;
protected $_itemFactory;

public __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProviderInterface,
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ItemFactory $itemFactory
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_wishlistProviderInterface = $wishlistProviderInterface;
    $this->_itemFactory = $itemFactory;
    ...
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$this->_itemFactory->create()->load($itemId);
if (!$item->getId()) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Item not found.'));
}
$wishlist = $this->_wishlistProviderInterface->getWishlist($item->getWishlistId());
if (!$wishlist) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Wishlist not found.'));
}
try {
    $item->delete();
    $wishlist->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
}
```

Comment: How you can get $itemId and $item in this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution.

```
protected $wishlist;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist
) {
    $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
}

public function execute()
{
    $customerId = 1;
    $productId = 6;
    $wish = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
    $items = $wish->getItemCollection();

    /** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $item */
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) {
            $item->delete();
            $wish->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get itemId by using customer session.There is one method in wishlist loadByCustomerId, please check that one.

Answer (score 0):

The wishlist item model itself should not be responsible for deletion of the item. I would suggest using the wishlist item resource model (`Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item`) as right now, there is no repository to do that.

I assume you already have the wishlist item id at this point as the question sounds like that.

**Constrcutor to inject necessary dependencies:**

```php
/**
 * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface
 */
protected \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ItemFactory
 */
private \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ItemFactory $wishlistItemFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item
 */
private \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item $wishlistItemResourceModel;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider,
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ItemFactory $wishlistItemFactory,
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item $wishlistItemResourceModel
) {
    $this->wishlistProvider = $wishlistProvider;
    $this->wishlistItemFactory = $wishlistItemFactory;
    $this->wishlistItemResourceModel = $wishlistItemResourceModel;
}
```

**And the logic to load and delete the specific wishlist item:**

```php
// Get wishlist item
$wishlistItem = $this->wishlistItemFactory->create();
// Populate it
$this->wishlistItemResourceModel->load($wishlistItem, $id);
// And finally, delete it
if ($wishlistItem->getId()) { // Ensure that item exists
    $this->wishlistItemResourceModel->delete($wishlistItem);
}
```

In the end, calling `$item->delete()` is calling `delete()` on the resource model, but when you call directly `delete()` on the resource model, you move the responsibility away from the model itself.